# How to get dictionary values in Python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, nltk

I'm working with python dictionaries and ntlk on some reviews.I have and input (`txt`)file which is a simple review. In a dictionary `all_dict.txt`. I have all words (negative and positive) with word polarities and value.

`all_dict.txt` looks like this

```
"acceptable":("positive",1),"good":("positive",1),"shame":("negative",2),"bad":("negative",4),...
```

I want to know how can I get this polarities from a dictionary and a number value for each word so that I can get an output like this:

```
"acceptable_positive":1,"good_positive":1,"shame_negative":2,"bad_negative":4
```

I tried with `dict.get()`, `dict.values` but I don't get what I want. Is there a method to fetch key and values automatically?:

I tried with my code:

```
f_all_dict=open('all_dict.txt','r',encoding='utf-8').read() 
f = eval(f_all_dict) 

result_all = {} 

for word in f.items():
    suffix, pol=result_all[word] #pol->polarity
    result_all[word + "_" + suffix] = pol
```

But I get `KeyError` if the word doesn't exist in an input file (review).

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, the `dict.items()` return a `dictitem` object contains tuples of key and value and when you want to pass it as a key to your dictionary it raise a `KeyError`.

```
suffix, pol=result_all[word]
```

Secondly you better to use `with` statement in order to dealing with external objects like files. And use `ast.literal_eval()` for evaluating your dictionary. Also you can access to your value's items, by using throwaway variables unpacking :-) within a dict comprehension.

```
from ast import literal_eval
with open('all_dict.txt','r',encoding='utf-8') as  f_all_dict:
    dictionary = literal_eval(f_all_dict.read().strip()) 

result_all = {"{}_{}".format(word, suffix): pol for word, (suffix, pol) in dictionary.items()}
```

Comment: "return a tuple of key and value" not true though, it returns a `dict_items` instance which can be iterated over.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen Indeed, I just missed the Python 3.x tag :-)

Comment: It helped, I used `literal_eval()` and modificated my code with this. I got results I wanted. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

After modification my code looks like this. I didn't use `with` statement and it is working good.

```
f_all_dict=open('all_dict.txt','r',encoding='utf-8').read()
f = literal_eval(f_all_dict)

result_all = {} 

 for word in f.items():
    result_all = {"{}_{}".format(word, suffix): pol * tokens.count(word) for word, (suffix, pol) in f.items()}
    print(result_all)
```